# How to prevent more than one click on an Anchor tag button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor tag (namely Cancel button) with a class attribute and href attribute in a jsp file .

I have written an `onclick` event for the class attribute in a seperate js file. So when the button is clicked, the onclick event executes and then takes to the href link.

When the button is clicked more than once it takes me to an empty page or an error page.

I want to prevent more than one click on the button.

I have tried using `event.preventdefault()` function inside my `onclick()` function but the href link is not working if I do that.
Any other way?

My JS code:

```
$('.cancel-btn').on('click',function(evt){
            //evt.preventDefault();
           //My Code            

        });
```

Comment: Have a look into the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w2wnuyv6/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method will perform click event only once:

```js
$('.cancel-btn').one('click',function(evt){
  // evt.preventDefault();
  // code here            
});
```

Also possible using jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method that may be more useful when the event should be removed conditionally:

```js
let count = 0; // or may be a boolean flag
$('.cancel-btn').on('click', function(evt){
  if (count == 0) {
    count++;
    // code here
  } else {
    return false;
    // or evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Or like this:

```js
$('.cancel-btn').on('click', function(evt) {
  // code here
  // then remove the event handler.
  $(this).off('click');
});
```

Comment: Good answer! It's always better to [link to the source](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and provide the relevant details directly in the post - "`.one()` is the same as `.on()` except the handler is unbound after the first invocation."

Comment: @RohitSharma have tried using one() method but your second answer worked for me :).. I have used preventDefault() in the else class instead of return false.Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a boolean flag to make sure the function executes only once

```
var executeOnce = false;
$('.cancel-btn').on('click',function(evt){
   if(!executeOnce){
     //evt.preventDefault();
     //My Code  
     executeOnce = true;
   }     
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go with one more way to do it using pointer-events as none 
https://jsfiddle.net/w2wnuyv6/1/

```
$('a[value="cancel"]').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'pointer-events': 'none'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a function like this:

```
function clickOnce (element ,listener){
    element.addEventListener("click", function (event){
        listener(event);
        element.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakerswgq/8e7vnw9w/)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the event is written on that `class`, you can use this simple code to ensure that its clicked only once:

```
$('.cancel-btn').on('click', function(evt) {
  // execue your code
  $(this).removeClass('cancel-btn');
});
```

This code will remove the class from the DOM and hence the `click` event will never get fired.

**Optionally**, You can use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event like so:

```
$(".cancel-button").off("click");
```

This will remove all click events bound to this element. In your code, it would be like:

```
    $('.cancel-btn').on('click', function(evt) {
      // execue your code
      $(this).off("click");
    });
```